# empathy and google hosts

Tags: gnome, empathy, online-accounts

**I set static ip in /etc/hosts for some google sites (Google is blocked frequently in China).**

**Then empathy cannot login with google account.**

How can I make empathy work with hosts binding?

I am sure earlier version empathy works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find use jabber protocol will get ride of this problem
As now(gnome 3.10), this problem is fixed